# adding rows to a table dynamically with asp controls

Tags: asp.net

This worked for me for about 5 minutes and now I have nothing. The object is to select the a number from the dropdown list and then use that number to assign how many rows will be added to table.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //variables for the number of rows and cells
                int numrows = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                int numcells = 3;
                for (int j = 0; j < numrows; j++)
                    {
                        HtmlTableRow r = new HtmlTableRow();
                        r.BgColor = "Gainsboro";
                        //demoTable.Rows.Add(r);

                        for (int i = 0; i < numcells; i++)
                            {
                                HtmlTableCell c = new HtmlTableCell();
                                c.InnerHtml = " row " + j.ToString() + ", cell " + i.ToString();
                                r.Cells.Add(c);    
                            }
                        demoTable.Rows.Add(r);
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is it html table or ASP table? what is demoTable?

Comment: if you are using html table then in aspx page add runat="server" and use that table id to insert rows. If you are using ASP control table then simpy add tablerow and tablecell instead of htmltablerow and htmltablecell respectively.

Comment: The code is fine. So it was working for you earlier? do you get any exception in Output window?

Comment: <table id = "demoTable" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: The error Im getting is"The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)s' has some invalid arguments"